# Atualizar imagem sempre que uma nova for escolhida?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8-1

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
private void foto_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    { // se teve sucesso na escolha de uma imagem da galeria
        BitmapImage imagem = new BitmapImage(); // cria uma imagem
        imagem.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto); // coloca o caminh da imagem escolhida nesse objeto de imagem
        using (IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        { // cria um gerenciamento de arquivos
            if (iso.FileExists("bloq.jpg"))
                iso.DeleteFile("bloq.jpg"); // se houver arquivo igual ele apaga
            IsolatedStorageFileStream fs = iso.CreateFile("bloq.jpg"); // cria um novo arquivo
            var bmp1 = new WriteableBitmap(imagem); // escreve a imagem escolhida em uma nova umagem editavel

            Extensions.SaveJpeg(bmp1, fs, 480, 800, 0, 90); // salva imagem
            imagem2.UriSource = new Uri(fs.Name, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute); // armazena o caminho da imagem salva em outro objeto de imagem
            fs.Close(); // fecha arquivo
        }
        fot.Source = imagem2; // pega o objeto com a  imagem recem salva e atribui a imagem presente na minha tela
        descricao.Text = "Agora pressione Salvar."; // muda um texto na tela
    }
}
```

O código só funciona na primeira vez, exemplo, o usuário abre o app, vai na tela e aperta para escolher um imagem, daí ele escolhe, aí sim ele atualiza a imagem na tela, mas se o usuário tentar escolher outra imagem, ele até substitui a imagem no armazenamento interno do app, mas não atualiza a imagem na tela, só quando o app é reiniciado que isso é atualizado.

Quero saber se há erro na lógica ou no código, como faço para sempre atualizar a imagem na tela? Independentemente de quantas vezes o usuário trocar a imagem

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de usares o path da Imagem usa o bitmap que recebes para fazer o set da imagem.

```
private void foto_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        { 
            // se teve sucesso na escolha de uma imagem da galeria
            var bmp = new BitmapImage();

            bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

            Img.Source = bmp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pode adicionar um exemplo na resposta? Assim ela fica mais completa e servirá de referencia não só para o criador da pergunta.